# I just added a extra column in my database, to add hashtags. But now my hashtags also saves in my blog column. Can someone help me out?

Tags: database

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once "inc/package.inc.php";
include "connect.php";


//Ga er vanuit dat het formulier correct is ingevuld
$correct = true;

//Sla de waarden op in een variabel

$title = $_POST['title'];
if(isset($_POST['title']) && $_POST['title'] != ''){
    $title = filter_var($_POST['title'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $correct = true;
} else {
    echo "<p id='popupr'>Geef een titel!</p>";
    $correct = false; //Toch een foute waarde, onthou dit!
}

$blog = $_POST['reactie'];
if(isset($_POST['reactie']) && $_POST['reactie'] != ''){
    $blog = filter_var($_POST['reactie'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $correct = true;
} else {
    $correct = false; //Toch een foute waarde, onthou dit!
}

$mobiel = $_POST['mobiel'];
if(isset($_POST['mobiel']) && $_POST['mobiel'] != ''){
    $mobiel = filter_var($_POST['mobiel'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $correct = true;
} else {
    $correct = false; //Toch een foute waarde, onthou dit!
}
```

This is where I save my hashtags in a variable called 'tweet'. Thats works.

```
$tweet = $_POST['hashtag'];
if(isset($_POST['hashtag']) && $_POST['hashtag'] != ''){
    $blog = filter_var($_POST['hashtag'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $correct = true;
} else {
    $correct = false; //Toch een foute waarde, onthou dit!
}

if(isset($_POST['btn_upload'])) {
    $img = $_FILES["file_img"];
    $filetmp = $_FILES["file_img"]["tmp_name"];
    $priority = 2;
    if (empty($img)) {
        $filename === null;
        $target === null;

    } else {
    $file = $_FILES["file_img"]["name"];
    $filetype = $_FILES["file_img"]["type"];
    // unieke toevoeging berekenen
    $uniqueId = uniqId();

    // een hash van het bestand, of data in bestand
    $hash    = sha1_file($filetmp);

    $filename = "image_".$uniqueId."-".$hash.".png";
    $target  = realPath("photo").DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$filename;

    move_uploaded_file($filetmp,$target);
    }

    $correct =  true;
}
```

This is where i check if everything is filled correctly.

```
//Was alles correct ingevuld?
if($correct){
    // voeg de reactie toe in de tabel blogs.
    $author = $_SESSION["name"];

    // voeg de reactie toe in de tabel blogs.
    include "datum.php";
```

I think it goes wrong here. It doesn't save properly. It's in the same order as my database. And on my site, it shows the hashtags instead of the blog post. Its very weird.

```
    try{
    $stmt = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO blogs(author, date, title, blog, mobiel, hashtag, priority, img_name, img_path) VALUES (:author, :date, :title, :blog, :mobiel, :hashtag, :priority, '$filename', '$target')");
    $stmt->bindValue(':author', $author);
    $stmt->bindValue(':date', $datum);
    $stmt->bindValue(':title', $title);
    $stmt->bindValue(':blog', $blog);
    $stmt->bindValue(':mobiel', $mobiel);
    $stmt->bindValue(':hashtag', $tweet);
    $stmt->bindValue(':priority', $priority);
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e;
    }
    $result = $stmt->execute();
    if(!$result) {
        print_r($stmt->errorInfo());
    } else {
        header('Location: index.php');
        exit;
    }

} else {
    //Er is ergens een foute waarde ingevoerd, geef de bezoeker de mogelijkheid om terug te gaan
    echo "<p>Er is een foute waarde ingevoerd, <a href=\"javascript:history.back();\">ga terug</a>.</p>";
} 

?>
```

Sorry for my English, I'm still learning.

Comment: your problem is that it shows hashtags instead posts, but in database all is filled correctly?

Then check where you print data. Must change some index of database result...

Comment: In also saves it in my 'blog' column. So that's why it shows my hashtags instead of my blog, because the blog isn't saved.

Comment: it's not usual, if you prepare a connection with parameters in correct order... it's the same order that you have in database right?
Try it using Mysqli instead PDO (i always use PHP 7 with mysqli and never get an issue like that..)

Comment: We aren't allowed to use Mysqli according to our teacher. We must use PDO

Comment: LoL... Good luck with that so, i suppose that you are using php 5.6 too because your teacher hadn't time to read the changelog and learn what's new...
Then, make a backup and you can try to insert blog as usual (without hashtags) and then perform an update of hashtag field. Check it if works, then check why isn't working the code you have now.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining the variable `$blog` with the content of `$_POST['hashtag']` and inserting it on the `blog` column, so you are getting the value if hashtag in it.

You need to fix it here:

```
if(isset($_POST['hashtag']) && $_POST['hashtag'] != ''){
    $blog = filter_var($_POST['hashtag'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $correct = true;
} else {
    $correct = false; //Toch een foute waarde, onthou dit!
}
```